# How to solve this recurrence relation: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I am having trouble with this recurrence relation.

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1

Can anyone help me in explaining how one would go about solving this to get to the answer of `O(n)`?

Comment: I've never been taught a method like that before, I'm not sure where to start with a tree?

Comment: A quick search for notes brings up http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-1.pdf.  Drawing a tree won't help you prove the recurrence, but it's **the** best method (other than experience) that I know of for solving a recurrence.  I highly recommend reading about it.

Comment: I honestly did try a lot of googling before I posted on here, but thanks for those notes they are very helpful!

Comment: I definitely can't blame you for not knowing what to search for if you've never seen anything like it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that `n` is a power of 2. For example, if `n = 8` and the base case `T(0) = 0` then the tree of recursive call looks like that:

```
                       1                                n = 8, depth 0
                      / \
                     /   \
                    /     \
                   /       \
                  /         \
                 /           \
                /             \
               /               \
              /                 \
             /                   \
            /                     \
           1                       1                    n = 4, depth 1
          / \                     / \
         /   \                   /   \
        /     \                 /     \
       /       \               /       \
      /         \             /         \
     1           1           1           1              n = 2, depth 2
    / \         / \         / \         / \
   /   \       /   \       /   \       /   \
  1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1           n = 1, depth 3
 / \   / \   / \   / \   / \   / \   / \   / \
0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0         n = 0, depth 4
```

The tree has `log(n) + 1` levels not counting the lowest level, because each node in this level has cost `0`. In order to calculate `T(n)`, in this case `T(8)`, you have to sum up all ones in the tree.

Notice that on the depth `i` there are `2^i` nodes, each with cost equal `1`.

So the formula for a sum of ones in the tree is:

`sum [from i = 0 to log(n)] 2^i`

this is a geometric series with `a_1 = 1` and `q = 2`, and you want to know the sum of first `log(n) + 1` values. This is given by the formula:

`(1 - 2^(log(n) + 1)) / (1 - 2) = 2n - 1`

So for `n = 8`, the result is `15`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is a good graphical representation of the computation in one of the comments. However, to extend this asymptotic to *all* numbers, you need additional properties (such as monotonicity of the function). This is what makes Theorem 4.1 in Cormen's book a bit tricky to prove

Answer (score 2):

A good explanation of such relations is given in Cormen et al `Introduction to algoithms'. Master Theorem 4.1 in that book treats all recurrent relations of the form T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n). for various combinations of f, a, and b. One of the cases in that theorem, case 2. can be applied to your example, giving the O(n) estimate. So, to answer your question, you cannot just *solve* such a relation in the sense of performing some routine computations to end up with a asymptotic, rather you observe that your situation belongs to a class of relations for which an estimate exists.

Comment: However, I'm given the base case of T(1) = 0. At this point shouldn't it be solvable through steps? I was taught that was true at least...

Comment: Sure, you can compute the sequence. One subtlety would be to interpret, say, what 3/2 stands for (that is, whether you interpret your relation as T(3) = 2T(floor(3/2))+1 or otherwise). Such a computation, however (even if you formalize the relation), would not help you *show* (read *prove*) that your T(n) = An + o(n), where o(n)/n tends to zero, although you can observe the pattern.

Comment: Is there any chance I could get you to show me how to properly compute the sequence? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, to simplify things, assume that your relation is T(n) = 2T(floor(n/2))+1. Then we get the following infinite loop: T(1)=0, T(2)=2T(2/2)+1=1, T(3)=2T(floor(3/2))+1=2T(1)+1=1, T(4)=2T(2)+1=3, and so on, ... You will not be able to get an analytical formula for this sequence though, since the continuous version of T is a fractal.

Comment: Can't you use this method:
T(n)=2T(n/2) +n
T(n) = 2(2T(n/4) +n/2) +n
T(n)=4T(n/4) +n+n = 4T(n/4) + 2n

In order to break it down, then find a pattern and substitute the base case in to find a solution?

Comment: Since you have T(n)=2T(n/2)+1, you computation will go as: T(n)=2(2T(n/4)+1)+1=4T(n/4)+2+1. If n is a power of 2, you can easily find that T(2^i)=T(2^i/2^i)+ 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(i-1) = 2^i so at least for powers of 2 T(n) = n. For other numbers, this computation breaks down for obvious reasons, even though the asymptotics stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

This type of recursions are solved using [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

In your case `a = 2`, `b = 2` and `f(n) = 1`. So `c = log2(2) = 1` and `O(n^1) > O(1)`, which means that we fall in the third case and therefore a complexity is `O(n)`.