# can t(n)=2t(n/2)+n^0.5/logn can be solved using masters theorem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, master-theorem

I have an argue with my friend ,we had an exam yesterday .I said it couldnt,he said it would be case 1 .Probably he is right,but I cant seem to understand why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: n^(0.5/log n) is a constant (=exp(0.5)) for all n!=1

Comment: sorry I didnt understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

For any value of n greater than 1, n^(0.5/log n) has a constant value of exp(0.5). This can be proved quite easily:

```
   x = n^(0.5/log n)
   log(x) = (log n) * 0.5 / (log n) = 0.5
=> x = exp(0.5) = 1.64872...
```

As a result, the second term of your expression can be treated as a constant. With a constant second term, your formula is equivalent to [t(n) = 2t(n/2) + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18294865/1679849), which has complexity O(n).

And yes, your friend is right. This corresponds to [case 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1), where the value of c in f(n) ∈ O(n^c) is zero.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I understand. The equesion was (n^0.5)/logn though. Is It still the same?